# Singleton with parameters and Lazy<Singleton>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, singleton

I have an issue with the new `Lazy` in .NET 4.0. I don't understand how to pass some application parameters at init.

This basic code is working well:

```
private static readonly Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation> lazy =
    new Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation>(() => new FactoryHospitalisation();

public static FactoryHospitalisation Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

private FactoryHospitalisation()
{
}
```

But I don't know how to update the lambda expression when I try to add some parameters, as in this following example:

```
private string _appId;
private string _siteCode;

private static readonly Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation> lazy =
    new Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation>(() => new FactoryHospitalisation("""" What kind of parameters go here ?? """"));

public static FactoryHospitalisation Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

private FactoryHospitalisation(string appId, string siteCode)
{
    _appId = appId;
    _siteCode = siteCode;
}
```

I know how to do this using the old thread safe with lock version, but it would be very cool to understand how to implement the new 4.0 patterns :)

EDIT: this class is to `BindModelToData` and reverse (EF to Model and Model to EF). I need to call some object from WCF, and WCF needs to have my application Id and site code to be correctly called.

I have tried to transform `Instance` in methods, but I don't know if it's correct.

```
private static string _appId;
private static string _siteCode;

private static readonly Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation> lazy =
    new Lazy<FactoryHospitalisation>(() => new FactoryHospitalisation());

public static FactoryHospitalisation Instance(string appId, string siteCode)
{
    _appId = appId;
    _siteCode = siteCode;

    return lazy.Value;
}

private FactoryHospitalisation()
{
}
```

Comment: You can just pass parameters to FactoryHospitalisation ctor, so you will need to show the actual code that doesn't compile for us to understand what you want. I mean, the answer to your question "What kind of parameters get here?" is simply: Strings.

Comment: Factory with parameters suggests, that you need DI-container instead of manually-created singletons.

Comment: As the constructor is private, I can't pass directly parameters at initialisation step. When I use it, I call FactoryHospitalisation.Instance.Foo. This parameters is Application Id to call WCF so it's global application. What is DI-container ?

Comment: @User.Anonymous: the definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection ; the one of the implementations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Oh ok, I've used this design pattern with Spring.Net. This is overkill for my need. In this case, I use Singleton instead full static class because I never use static class (too limited, no interface, no mock, no oriented object).